# Finding and replacing multiple items in R

Tags: r

As a newbie to R i am having to write all my find and replacement statements one line at time (see code below)
Is it possible to do this in a more succinct way (i.e. one line only)

```
YP$gender <- replace(as.character(YP$gender), YP$gender == "Female", "F")   
YP$gender <- replace(as.character(YP$gender), YP$gender == "Male", "M")
```

Comment: Read about factors, ifelse, and switch.

Comment: What kind of vector is `YP$gender`? What does `class(YP$gender)` and `attributes(YP$gender)` return?

Answer (score 2):

If just two replacements use 'ifelse':

```
YP$gender <- ifelse(as.character(YP$gender) == "Female", "F", "M")
```

Else I would use left_join:

```
# Data
df <- data.frame(value = sample(1:3,10, replace = TRUE),
                 gender = sample(c("male", "female", "x"), 10, prob = c(0.4,0.4,0.2), replace = TRUE))

# Creating replacements
replace <- data.frame(gender = c("male", "female"), gender_short = c("m", "f"))

# Making replacements
library(dplyr)
df <- left_join(df, replace)
df

       value gender gender_short
1      1 female            f
2      2 female            f
3      3      x         <NA>
4      2   male            m
5      3 female            f
6      3      x         <NA>
7      3 female            f
8      1      x         <NA>
9      3   male            m
10     3   male            m
```

Comment: We would need another ifelse to check if it is M... otherwise this will recode X as M too.

Comment: Hi I am afraid I posted a bad example as I have several cases where I have more than two replacements

Comment: I made an answer for that too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use '%in%' for multiples comparations instead of '=='.

```
replace(as.character(YP$gender), YP$gender %in% c("Male","Female"), c("M", "F"))
```

EDIT: Sorry this code won't work as I tought.

But you can use loops to solve it.

```
YP = c("a","b","b","a","c")

keys = c("a", "b", "c")
rep_value = c("A", "B", "C")

for(index in 1:length(keys) ) {
  sub_key = keys[index]
  sub_rep_value = rep_value[index]

  value_index = which(YP %in% sub_key)
  YP[value_index] = sub_rep_value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends how many targets and replacements you have. If you have a lot then the easiest way is probably to create a merge file with two columns, one with the target and one with the replacement with as many rows as unique elements. If that merge file is called `df` then the code would look something like:

```
library(dplyr)
YP <- YP %>%
  merge(df, by = "gender", all.x = T)
```

If there aren't too many unique instances to replace then instead of using nested ifelse statements, you could use `case_when` from `dplyr`. You can chain together the logic using pipes `%>%`

```
library(dplyr)
YP %>%
  mutate(gender = case_when(
    gender == "Female" ~ "F",
    gender == "Male"   ~ "M,
    TRUE               ~ gender
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have factor column, so we just need to change the labels, something like this:

```
YP$gender <- factor(YP$gender, labels = c("F", "M"))
```

Reproducible example:

```
x <- factor(c("Female", "Male", "Female"))
x
# [1] Female Male   Female
# Levels: Female Male

#Check the levels
levels(x)
# [1] "Female" "Male"  

# relabel
x <- factor(x, labels = c("F", "M"))
# [1] F M F
# Levels: F M
levels(x)
# [1] "F" "M"
```

Comment: Or `substr(YP$gender, 1, 1)`